# Problema al llamar a procedimiento almacenado desde Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Tengo un problema al intentar acceder a un procedimiento específico almacenado en **SQL Server** desde **Java**. El procedimiento almacenado recibe un **XML** como parámetro, y devuelve otro. Un ejemplo de llamada es el siguiente:

```
DECLARE @xml AS NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @result AS NVARCHAR(2000)

SET @xml='<ROOT>
            <PARAMETROS>
              <PARAM valor="..." nombre="..."/>
              <PARAM valor="..." nombre="..."/>
              (...)
            </PARAMETROS>
          </ROOT>'
SET @result=''

EXEC dbo.procedimiento @xml, @result output
```

Esta llamada desde el propio **SQL Server** (Con datos reales) funciona bien, y me devuelve el **XML** deseado. Hice la prueba a ejecutar el procedimiento desde un programa en **C#** y también funciona correctamente. Sin embargo desde una aplicación **Java** no recibo ninguna respuesta.

En un principio pensé que podría ser un problema de conectividad desde Java, pero no, ya que **otros procedimientos con exactamente la misma estructura me devuelven respuesta**. Por lo que me puse a depurar este procedimiento y descubrí que varias partes del código eran las que estaban cortando la ejecución y que, si las comentaba, hacían que funcionara correctamente. Son las siguientes:

```
declare @Fechas TABLE (
  [fecha] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL 
)

INSERT INTO @fechas VALUES (@fecha)
```

Cada vez que en el procedimiento se declaraba una variable **TABLE** y se hacía algún tipo de inserción en ella, la llamada al procedimiento desde Java no me devolvía nada. Buscando una solución, encontré este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552404/problems-with-table-variables-in-sql-server-called-from-java) en Stack Overflow. Que habla de diferentes comportamientos con estas variables **TABLE** según la aplicación que se usa, devolviendo resultados en Java que pueden interpretarse como que ya se ha acabado la ejecución del procedimiento.

La llamada se está haciendo de la siguiente forma:

```
Object result = getEm().createNativeQuery("Exec [dbo].[procedimiento] :xml, :result")
    .setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 10000)
    .setParameter("xml", xml)
    .setParameter("result", result)
    .getResultList();
```

¿Cual sería la mejor forma de solucionar esto?. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré una solución. Como comentaba en la pregunta, cada vez que se realizaba una inserción en una variable **TABLE** en el procedimiento se devuelve el recuento de las filas afectadas. Esto en **C#** o en el propio **SQL Server** no afectaba para nada, ya que no lo tenía en cuenta. Pero **Java** lo interpretaba como el resultado final y cortaba la ejecución.

La mejor manera que encontré para evitar esto es modificar el procedimiento y definir al principio del mismo la propiedad `NOCOUNT` a `ON`. De la siguiente manera:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;  
GO  
-- Código del procedimiento almacenado.
```

Adjunto también el [enlace a la documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).